# How to detect if player is near to a GameObject(C#)Unity5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can i possibly detect if the player is near at the object .
Without the help of raycast.

Here is my code:

```
[SerializedField]
Transform obj1;

public GameObject player;

void Update(){
    if(obj1.transform.position - player.position < 5) {
       audio.Play();
    }
}
```

This is what i like to obtain . How can i do it like that. Help please

Comment: `Vector3.Distance`

Comment: reference for [Vector3.Distance function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj1.transform.position - player.position` will return a `Vector3`. You can use the magnitude of that vector as your distance:

```
if ((obj1.transform.position - player.position).magnitude < 5.0f)
    audio.Play();
```

As a bit of a performance tip, you can save an expensive square-root operation by instead using the magnitude squared:

```
if ((obj1.transform.position - player.position).sqrMagnitude < 25.0f)
    audio.Play();
```

Comment: Can you explain to me sir why do it always have sqrMagnitude? How far is it going to be?

Comment: @TheGinxx009 If you don't need the exact distance, then distance-squared is cheaper to calculate because it doesn't need to calculate a square root. It's also acceptable in this situation because if `dist < n`, then `dist^2 < n^2`.

Comment: I've got a big problem . The audio gone insane

void FixedUpdate(){
  AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
  if((SampleTrash.transform.position - thisCamera.transform.position).sqrMagnitude < 25.0f){
   audio.clip = third;
   audio.PlayOneShot (third);
  }
 }

Comment: @TheGinxx009 Define "gone insane". Though my guess is that it's playing the audio on every update for as long as the objects are close enough together. Add a check that only plays the clip if it isn't currently playing.

Comment: float nextSoundTime = 3f;
if((SampleTrash.transform.position - thisCamera.transform.position).sqrMagnitude < 25.0f){

   if (Time.time >= nextSoundTime) {
    audio.clip = third;
    audio.PlayOneShot (third);
    nextSoundTime = Time.time + third.length;
   }
  }
This doesnt work >.<
The audio is always repeating

Comment: @TheGinxx009 Check for `!audio.IsPlaying` instead of doing the time thing.

Comment: got the same result sir.

Comment: @TheGinxx009 Then perhaps this should move to a new question. You'll get more complete answers that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can find whether an object is near another object with the following code:

```
float distance = Vector3.Distance(object1.transform.position, object2.transform.position);
float maxDistance = 10.0f;
bool isNear = distance <= maxDistance;
```